# How can I show a large image, initially scaled to screen, but allow zooming?

Tags: html, css

My question is identical to this other question:

[CSS: Display image with position:fixed but allow user zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41552751/css-display-image-with-positionfixed-but-allow-user-zoom)

I have a large map (5000x3000) that needs to be shown initially scaled to fit the screen, but allow the user to zoom.  The code I have now solves the first problem of initially scaling, but it doesn't allow zooming -- it does this weird jiggling at the edges instead.

Linking directly to the image didn't work, it showed at full size initially, and I didn't understand the only answer "make width on viewport".  I'm at best a beginner with CSS/HTML so please give details.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="./map.png">
</body>
```

The target system is Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Are you trying to zoom on mouse-wheel or any button click ?

Comment: both would be nice, but mouse-wheel primarily